# Internal storage used space readings differ

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, settings, internal-storage

**Context**

I have a Motorola XT1068 phone with Android 6.0. It has 8GB of internal storage, of which 2.5GB are for the OS and 5.5GB for data. At one point, when connecting it to my computer, I noticed that the used/free space for the internal memory has different values depending on where you're looking.

**The readings**

- Android settings > Storage & USB: 4.79/5.51GB used
- Android settings > Storage & USB > Internal storage: [~3.3GB used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klOsK.png) when you add all up
- file explorer front page: 4.84/5.51GB used
- file explorer > browse to `/` > select all > Properties: [7.92GB used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCdO9.png) (this must also include the OS)
- PC > My Computer reading: 179MB/5.50GB free, so ~5.32GB used.

If the cache keeps growing, it will eventually reach a point where the PC reading says no space is left, yet the phone says there still is.

I am honestly at a loss on what reading is the correct one, but also on why they differ so much, especially why the PC shows much less free space than the phone makes it seem.

I also have a memory card in the phone, however the free/used space data remains constant across Settings/file explorer/PC.